# LPTHW - Ex:25 - values are not returned from a couple of function calls - why?

Tags: python-2.7

LPTHW - Ex25 - Code copied from the book

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    return word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    return word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words and then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

I tried this exercise today on WindowsPowerShell.

The last two calls (refer: screenshot below) do not return any values.

```
PS C:\mystuff> python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ex25 import *
>>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
>>> sentence
'All good things come to those who wait.'
>>> print_first_and_last(sentence)
>>> print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
>>>
```

Could you please help me understand why they are not returning any values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It din't return or print any value as you were not returning the value from inner function, I've modified the code to print the values in the function now.

```
def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print (print_first_word(words))
    print (print_last_word(words))

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words and then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print (print_first_word(words))
    print (print_last_word(words))

sentense = "All good things come to those who wait"
print_first_and_last(sentense)
print_first_and_last_sorted(sentense)
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. Then again, it is strange that it works without "print()" for the author. Is it because of Python version 2.7.1 vs 2.7.9 (the one that I use) ?